# new column in database doesn't recive data from form cakephp

Tags: cakephp, fill

I had a working form in CakePhp 2.X. I added a new column of type `varchar` in the mysql database and updated correctly from in the view. When I submit the form, old inputs are saving correctly but the new column is not. I tried in the cake php controller to match the data:

```
$data['table']['newcolumn']
```

but it doesn't work.  Where is my mistake?

Comment: Could you post the code for that action in the controller and the view as well?  Also, are the names definitely correct (does the 'newcolumn' in your array match exactly with the name of your new column)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

clear your cache files, Cakephp creates model cache in

> app/tmp/cache/model

You need to delete cache for that particular model